# How to set roles of drupal "and" with each other?

Tags: users

I need to show a block to users who have multiple roles. For example: accountant and employee.
I do not want to use permissions. I need a simple solution.

is there anyone who can direct me?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [hook_block_view_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.api.php/function/hook_block_view_alter/7)() in your theme's template.php

```
function MYTHEME_block_view_alter(&$data, $block) {
  global $user;

  $roles = array('accountant', 'employee');
  $required_roles = array_diff($roles, $user->roles);

  if ($block->delta == 'YOUR-BLOCK-DELTA' && !empty($required_roles)) {
    $data['content'] = $data['subject'] = NULL;
  }
}
```

The array_diff() here will check that the roles the user needs to have appear in the user's roles array. If either accountant or employee do not appear in $user->roles it will set the block's content/subject to NULL and Drupal will not display it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Context](https://www.drupal.org/project/context) module which has possibility to display content and it supports AND/OR operations for specific conditions (such as role selection).

Comment: there isn't any condition base on username. you can define it under roles. nothing changes!!

Comment: @shekoufeh Why there should be a condition per username? It's not Drupal-way. For that reason there are roles. You apply specific role to the username to which you want to show a block.

Answer (score 0):

You can show a block for specific roles on the configurationpage of the block.
Navigate to admin/structure/block and click "configure" next to the block you want to set the restrections. Then scroll down to "visibility settings" and select for which roles the block must be visible:
[image]

Comment: I guess if we do like this, the individual roles (who have only accountant or employee) can access the block. But OP don't want that.

Comment: I do not think this solution works for both roles(and condition only)

Comment: in this way accountants or employees can see the block to! I need to display it just to people who have both of rolls employee AND accountant!